# Can someone become a doctor or work in health sector by completing a PhD degree in Philosophy in Medicine?

Tags: phd, medicine, philosophy

- [three-year Ph.D. in Philosophy, in association with Philosophy & Medicine Project](https://www.kcl.ac.uk/study/funding/peter-sowerby-studentship-2021-22)

If someone completes this Ph.D. degree, can he either become a doctor or work in a hospital/clinic or health sector?

I mean, is there any option/possibility/potential?

Comment: The degree is in philosophy, *not*  in a medical field. You can still hope that you end up working in the health sector (for example, experts dealing with ethics have been important during the pandemic) but not as a medical practitioner.

Comment: As clearly described on the page you linked, this PhD project is about philosophical topics in medicine. If you want to become a medical doctor in the UK, you would need a medical degree, for example https://www.kcl.ac.uk/study/undergraduate/courses/medicine-mbbs.

Answer (score 4):

No, if by "doctor" you mean physician, and/or by "work in a hospital" etc. you mean "treating people with medical conditions".

A PhD is a kind of doctorate, but a doctorate in philosophy does not qualify you to treat ill people.

Depending on the specifics of the research project that students in the particular program you are referring to carry out, they might be able to work in the health sector broadly conceived, but they will not practice healthcare. Managerial or policy-related tasks come to mind.

Comment: have you checked the link?

Comment: @user366312 In the link you provided, the degree is in Philosophy, not in Medicine. I believe this answer is correct.

Comment: @user366312 yes. Among the first things it says "PhD in Philosophy".